# Why does this statement fail?

Tags: mysql, create-table

Why doesn't this statement work?

```
CREATE TABLE capacidad (
  cod_capacidad INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cod_area INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  capacidad VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(cod_capacidad),
 INDEX capacidad_FKIndex1(cod_area),
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_area)
   REFERENCES AREA(cod_area)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   )
 ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Looks fine. What's the error?

Comment: does your `AREA` table exist ?

Comment: sorry, i found the error: AREA is a keyword, this reason was the problem, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

to not get error 150: you must check the following :

1. The two tables must be **ENGINE=InnoDB**.
2. The two tables must have the same charset.
3. The PK column(s) in the parent table and the FK column(s) must be the same data type.
4. The PK column(s) in the parent table and the FK column(s), if they have a define collation type, must have the same collation type;
5. If there is data already in the foreign key table, the FK column value(s) must match values in the parent table PK columns.

Hope this helps.

ps: u should share your other table also.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create index outside `CREATE TABLE` statement using [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//create-index.html) syntax:

edit: My fault, I thought about mssql.

PS. This statement works in my DB.